# How to run a GEE regression for repeated measures with a response binomial variable?

Tags: r

Im trying to perform logisting regression for generalized estimated equations (GEE). I use the Ideo_Dich(consists of 0 and 1) as my response variable with:

```
sample2$Ideo_Dich <- ordered(factor(sample2$Ideo_Dich))

library (multgee)
nomLORgee(Ideo_Dich~ square+round, data=sample2,
                                 id= Politician_ID,repeated=Country_ID)
```

but I get the following error message:

```
The response variable should have more than 2 categories
```

My sample dataset is like:

```
Politician_ID Country_ID Ideo_Dich    round square
           <int>      <int> <ord>        <dbl>  <dbl>
 1          3917          1 0          0.374   -0.486
 2          3921          1 0          0.682   -0.580
 3          3931          1 0          0.463   -0.801
 4          3932          1 0          0.00806 -0.296
 5          3935          1 0         -0.250   -0.485
 6          3936          1 0          0.814   -0.684
 7          3937          1 0         -0.0876  -0.421
 8          3942          1 0          0.630   -0.738
 9          3944          1 0          0.0779  -0.499
10          3945          1 0          0.549   -1.30
```

As Im new to the regression methodologies I would like some guidance on this.

Comment: Since the package appears to be for multinomial response variables, my guess is this error is telling you that it won't work for binomial (i.e., only 2 category) response variables.

Comment: Then I guess the answer would be a package that runs a GEE regression for repeated measures(Country_ID)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GEE are population average models. You need to specify only a single ID in the model. If you can only choose politicians or county as the ID and a correlation structure.
sample2$Ideo_Dich <- factor(sample2$Ideo_Dich)
library(geepack)
Ideo_Dich~ geeglm(square+round, data=sample2,id= Politician_ID, corstr="exchengable")
summary(Ideo_Dich)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your response variable is binary and not categorical. This particular model (nomLORgee) is for multinomial GEE regression. Thus, gee or geepack packages and binomial GEE regression should suffice. The above is a good example of this.